# Font is not getting applied on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Defined like this in css

```
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src:url(../font/schonanblack.ttf);
}
```

JS Error

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "myFirstFont" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: `http://www.himanshu1234.net63.net/MoneyManager/css/font/schonanblack.ttf`
```

And Used like this

```
.UserName2
{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    /*background-color:#0CF;*/
    color:#666;
    font-family:myFirstFont;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:500;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:7px;
}
```

It is getting applied on chrome but not on Firefox and IE

when I changed it from `url(../font/schonanblack.ttf)` to `url(font/schonanblack.ttf)`.. It started to work in IE but stopped in chrome also.. and still not working in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a firefox security policy not allowing you to load fonts from a folder above the css-file. Simple version: you can't use .. in font-face source in firefox.

Do as follow:

- move myfont.ttf into /public_html/css/font/myfont.ttf
- change your css like the following:

.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(font/schonanblack.ttf);
}
```

This bugs are restrictions from browser sandbox. They need to ensure security between different domains ("cross domain policy"). You would have seen an error in firebug console, which is a kinda good tool for debugging.

Comment: the file is in public html
Then the font is in.. a folder found in public html

Comment: Please detail the folder structure:
/public_html/your_css.css and 
/public_html/font/schonanblack.ttf ?
The font-face is defined in your_css.css ?

Comment: it worked in IE but still not working in firefox now.. and also stopped working in chrome!!

Comment: public_html/font/myfont.ttf

public_html/css/mycss.css

Comment: You did not mention it was running fine in chrome/ie.
One can find that firefox got a stricter security model about where fonts can be loaded from (only allowing fonts coming from below).
So try to move your font into a subfolder and then stop using the .. relative path.

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/956597

Comment: public_html/font/myfont.ttf ............public_html/css/mycss.css..... public_html/myfile.php

Comment: It was working in chrome but when I changed it from url(../font/schonanblack.ttf) to url(font/schonanblack.ttf).. It started to work in IE but stopped in chrome also.. and still not working in firefox

Comment: Do as follow: move myfont.ttf into /public_html/css/font/myfont.ttf
Then you  change your css to `src:url(font/schonanblack.ttf)`;